# How to reverse an array?

Tags: java, java1.4

```
XXXXXVO[] general = XXXX.getXXXX();

 Comparator comparator = new Comparator() {
        DateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        public int compare(Object obj1, Object obj2) {

            XXXXX gen11 = (XXXXXVO) obj1;
            XXXXX gen22 = (XXXXXVO) obj2;

            String firstString = gen11.getXXXXX().toString();
            String secondString = gen22.getXXXX().toString();

            if (secondString == null || firstString == null) {
                return 0;
            }


            return f.parse(firstString).compareTo(f.parse(secondString));

        }
    };      

    Arrays.sort(general, comparator);
```

Above is the code which sort the array general in ascending order.
I want that in  descending order.
How can I reverse this in JDK 1.4??

Answer (score 2):

Just reverse the order in which you compare:

```
return f.parse(secondString).compareTo(f.parse(firstString))
```

Answer (score 1):

I have not gone through the entire code. What I understood is you need to reverse the order , so multiply the result of `compareTo()` with `-1`.

```
return -1*f.parse(firstString).compareTo(f.parse(secondString));
```

To sort based on dates , you have to  convert the `String` to `Date` in the Comparator which you are already doing using `f.parse(firstString)` and use `Date`'s [compareTo()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#compareTo%28java.util.Date%29).

Comment: The array General will have many labels like date,amount...
I want to sort that array in descending order based on the date.
The below code will get date values form the array
  String firstString = gen11.getXXXXX().toString();
            String secondString = gen22.getXXXX().toString();

So is that I can directly sort into descending order by using firstString  and firstString or I shld first sort into ascending order and ther I shld reverset.If it is so how I can reverse that?

Comment: What type is the array ? Is it an `Object[]` ?